# Determining a Part-of-Speech without nlkt or spacey but rather regex

Tags: nltk, spacy

How can I identify if a word is a noun, adjective or verb without using an external library like nlkt or spacey but simply using regex

Comment: You can't replace a POS tagger using a statistical model with regex.

Comment: But you can attribute certain criteria such as 'Any word ending with er is verb'

Comment: No, you can't. To give a trivial example, "beer" is not a verb. Many words can have different parts of speech depending on context, like in "I can open a can". You are underestimating the complexity of this task.